# How to implement multi-tenant access from a windows service to a public WebApi securely

Tags: c#, windows, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a windows service (Headless) that can be configured to talk with our WebApi in a multi-tenant scenario. The closest example I could find was the one posted here [Calling web APIs in a daemon or long-running process](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon). The problem with this sample is doesn't show how you would deal a multi-tenant scenario. If you use the same AppKey for every tenant wouldn't it be possible to impersonate another tenant if someone decided to search the app for the ClientID and AppKey? It seems like one way around this would be to generate a new AppKey for every tenant who joins our service. This AppKey would need to be provided to the windows service as a configuration parameter when customer installed the service. Is this the correct approach? It doesn't seem like this the correct direction since it wouldn't be obvious from the AAD portal which AppKey is associated with which tenant. Looks like you would have to manage this yourself. I know you have to pass tenant ID as part of the authority, but these IDs are not like AppKey or passwords. What's the correct approach for this scenario?

I also look at this sample [Building a multi-tenant web API secured by Azure AD](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-multitenant-windows-store/blob/master/README.md). Unfortunately this sample is a windows store app. It has UI, so it can do the typical consent dance with AAD. Obviously, I windows service can't use this approach. I may be able self-host a WebApp in a windows service, force the user to go through the consent process at least once, so the token is cache like in this sample. However, what do I use as the RedirectUrl? This is not a Windows store app so I can't use

```
WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();
```

It's not clear to me if this scenario is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Your latter method is the way to go. Don't create one key per tenant, that will be a key mgmt nightmare.

Create one app, and have it request the 'application permissions' needed by your service. Before your service can get a token in a given tenant, you will indeed need to get interactive consent from a tenant admin, who will provide the authZ your app needs. Then your app will be able to request and receive tokens just like in the daemon article you reference.

We usually recommend you ask admins to go through consent when they sign up for your service, which usually has some interactive flow. You can definitely host a site just for this purpose. But you could also just copy the URL used to request consent from the admin, and send that to your customers instead of hosting some web page. You could send the URL to them in email or something. You don't need to worry about capturing the authorization response after they consent - you just need them to login and grant consent.

Comment: Is it not a problem that each tenant would use the same client id + client secret to get tokens? Wouldn't this make it easy for tenants to impersonate each-other?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend implementing JSON Web Tokens (JWT) - see [JSON Web Token in ASP.NET Web API 2 using Owin](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/). Then you can use [JWT Refresh Tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/refresh-token), that  essentially allow a user to remain authenticated forever, but they can be revoked.

Comment: I can get a token using ADAL on server using the currently logged in user, embed it in the installation package of the windows service that's downloaded from the server. However, it doesn't look like ADAL supports the notion of using existing token. It would be really nice to be able to use ADAL to handle the refreshing of the token.